# Highly linear amplifier for tiny voltages

Tags: amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

I have a tiny voltage which ranges between 0V to 0.05V (bandwidth of this signal is <100kHz) that I need to amplify to 0V to 3.3V. If I would like my final voltage to be distorted only upto 0.5%, what is the best circuit to accomplish this?

P.S. Yes, I have considered using an Op-amp, however, as far as I know, opamps are very non-linear in the lower and upper end output voltage (the output voltage starts to saturate?).

Edit 1:
I only have access to 0V and 3.3V.

Comment: An op-amp would be great for this application. I don't know why you think they are non-linear...the "lower and upper end" *of what*? Probably, you should ask a question about whatever it is about op-amps you don't quite understand. Did you read that on an audiophile forum?

Comment: ^ What he said. I'd cast an eye over Linear Tech's website, there's some classic app notes & papers written by Jim Williams and Bob Pease about this sort of thing, might give you some pointers.

Comment: If my op-amp has +3.3V connected to VDD, and 0V connected to VSS, shouldn't the gain become non-linear as the input voltage gets closer to the rail voltages?

Comment: @PhilFrost I meant that the output starts to saturate or distort as it approaches the rail voltages. Also, no I did not read that on audiophile... its based on past expirence

Comment: What are you feeding the output into? If it's an ADC, I'd just avoid the ends of the ranges and accept the small loss in range.

Comment: @pjc50 yes, this will feed an ADC. how can I avoid the ends of the range?

Comment: Choose a slightly smaller gain and DC offset, e.g a gain of 50 and offset of 0.5V will give you up to 0.5V to 3V. However, I think you might _need_ a negative supply rail in order to handle input near 0 - someone may correct me on this.

Comment: No component, opamp or not, will maintain distortion performance when operating close to the rail. You **must** supply voltage supplies outside your largest required output swing, or equivalently, use a signal swing that stops short of the rails in both directions. Once you've done this, opamps are the ideal component for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Murata have a range of power supply convertors that are intended for this application: -

[image]

The one I've highlighted will take a supply of 3.3 volts and produce output voltages of +/-5V. The outputs are isolated too. The one immediately above is the same but produces +/-3.3 volt outputs. All are rated at 1W. There are plenty of this type of converter around. Cost in Farnell for the one highlighted is just over £5.

So this overcomes the op-amp clipping problem.

Regards the actual op-amp, you need an amplification of 66 and a signal that is up to 100kHz. This implies you are looking for an op-amp with a GBW product of 6.6MHz BUT to keep distortion down to a decent limit you should look for something with a GBW of at least ten times this figure.

I'd consider using the [LT6236](http://www.linear.com/product/LT6236) from Linear technology. It's got a GBW of around 200MHz and very low noise figures. It's also got rail-to-rail output swing capability and an input offset of 0.5mV max. Supply current is only 3.5mA so it's pretty suitable for the OP I would say providing DC accuracy at the output is acceptable as being up to +/-33mV.

As with any op-amp of this type look to keep input driving source impedances low to minimize effects of bias currents AND make sure the power supply pins are properly decoupled.

Answer (score 2):

Op-amps will only saturate when the output gets too close to the supply rails. If you want a high quality 0 to 3.3V output signal, you may have to use +/-5V rails for the amplifier.

You have not given any requirements as to input bias current, DC stability or anything else that would help nail down which op-amp might be suitable. I'll suggest one I've suggested before for precise AC signals - [OPA209](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa209.pdf). If you need high accuracy, I'd suggest two stages since the GBW product is only 18MHz and you need a gain of 66.

Comment: understood... so just make the VDD higher than needed (+5V) and VSS lower than needed (-5V) inorder to avoid the non-linearity effects... but what if I only have access to 0V and 3.3V?

Comment: @hassan789 Can you use a bridge output - in effect two op-amps where one inverts and one doesn't each with half the gain and only swinging to half the rail voltage.

Comment: You could make +5 and -5 from 3.3V with a chip or two. If you really need to swing from 0 to 3.3 with low distortion at 100kHz, the options are limited.

Comment: What @SpehroPefhany said. If you only need a few mA on either rail, you could tap into the supply rails of any MAX232-type device.

Comment: ok, I will look into creating a dual supply from 3.3

Comment: @Andyaka can you please elaborate some more... preferably submit your suggestion as an answer

Comment: @hassan789 a bridge output is a differential output as opposed to a single-ended output referenced to ground - it may not be suitable for you requirements hence it isn't an answer, rather it is a question to YOU.

Comment: @Andyaka to answer your questions, yes, I am able to do that. But I am having trouble visualizing the opamp configuration... (i can use 2 ADCs to take a differential measurement, right?)

Comment: @hassan789 look at the diagrams in here http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa064a/sloa064a.pdf - probably figure 21 will help the most - it shows two op-amps driving a speaker. The load is unimportant but the fact that the total peak voltage delivered to the speaker is nearly twice the supply rail is important.

Comment: @Andyaka I don't think this will work... the more I think about it, the more I think I will need a DC bias OR negative rail.

Comment: @hassan789 As Spehro implies earlier on, you can buy modules that take in 3.3V and spew out +/- 5V - check-out the guys at Traco.